# How to get ServletConfig object in Filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Is there any way to get `ServletConfig` object of the servlet in a `Filter` applied to that servlet?

Edit-> The scenerio is i have mentioned the names of roles(who can access the servlet)
 in the 'init-param' of the serlvet declaration in web.xml

The applied filter will check(using ServletConfig) whether the person who is trying to access the servlet is authorized(in roles) to access it or not.

Comment: If you can't find what you are looking for then probably you may explain what you are trying to achieve instead

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `ServletConfig` is tied to a specific servlet, just like `FilterConfig` is for filters.

Which servlet config you want to access inside a filter? Note that a filter does not necessarily need to delegate to an underlying servlet directly. It can pass request to another servlet, choose servlet based on some condition or even handle the request completely without touching any servlet.

That being said these two abstractions are not accessible within each other.