# How can I get the Current Servlet Object in a filter?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, web, servlet-filters

I need do something special to specific Servlet class object by :

```
if (currentServlet instanceof SpecificServlet) {
      // do something special...
}
```

But I can not find a method in FIlter to get the currentServlet.

Comment: Filter is a layer ahead of Servlet and it is not connected with servlet, so why do you need the instance of Servlet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as *current servlet* in a filter. In fact sometimes the filter itself handles the whole request and no servlet is needed.

What do you want to achieve? Note that if you want to run some method on a servlet you might get unexpected results as servlets are shared between multiple concurrent requests. You'll probably need some sort of indirection, like storing a request or session attribute in filter and retrieving it in servlet.

## See also

- [How to get ServletConfig object in Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191904)